# Oracle Fusion Middleware SOA 11 silent configuration through config.sh

Tags: oracle, configuration, soa, middleware, fusion

I need to install Oracle SOA Suite 11.1.1.7 on headless server.

This one:
[Fusion Middleware Installation Guide for Oracle SOA Suite and Oracle Business Process Management Suite](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/install.1111/e13925/toc.htm)

I managed to install it through responseFile.rsp, which is a standard Oracle Universall installer file.

The second step is to configure a domain through 
$SOA_ORACLE_HOME/common/bin/config.sh

This give me only a GUI Configurator like this one described here:

[Fusion Middleware Creating Domains Using the Configuration Wizard](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e14140/configuration_screens.htm#WLDCW202)

There is a console mode, but there is also an option --silent like in installer before, where variables are set in responseFile.rsp.

But I can't find any description of variables or responseFile.rsp which I can set for silent configuration setup I don't really want do it through console mode, because I want to provision domain through ansible role. Is there anybody who has an experience with this kind of instalation?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved OSB domain setup using WLST and ansible. I have used below as my reference.

```
    http://myofwexperiments.blogspot.in/2016/01/soa-clustered-domain.html
```

Try and keep me posted for any clarifications

Comment: I have found that it is possible to use https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e14144/toc.htm . So create plain domain with GUI installer and than pack through pack command. Unpack on new installation. Not successfully tested yet, but that should be a way.

Comment: As the document suggests, no customizations are possible with this approach. Ideally, in real world scenario, pack/unpack is used with Managed server template but not with domain template.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. But that means it's not possible to do it pack/unpack style. We have try it but without the reasonable result. Only tar complete domain, mean $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/{our_domain} and untar on new weblogic instance works (it's possible to log in to weblogic console), but the question is which side effect this "hack" has.

Comment: I don't presume any side effects. But a lot of manual intervention needed to configure data sources and config.xml at least. Also, domain name can't be changed if you want a distinct name to every environment. 

WLST way is worth giving a try. I have tried and succeeded with OSB.